# Black Screen on Simulator (viewDidLoad)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, viewdidload

I've searched a bit and I can't seem to figure out why my simulator screen is black when I run it. The copyright page still loads up but the view after it is black. I think it may have something to do with the `viewdidLoad()`. I could be wrong because I'm new to Swift. Please help me. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var Picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var Button: UIButton!
    var PlacementAnswer = 0

    var Array = ["First View Controller", "Second View Controller"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Picker.delegate = self
        Picker.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return Array [row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return Array.count
    }
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    @IBAction func Select(sender: AnyObject){

        if (PlacementAnswer == 0){
            performSegueWithIdentifier("FirstView", sender: sender)
        }else{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondView", sender: sender)
        }
        return 
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        NSLog("Hello")
        PlacementAnswer = row
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug! Put a breakpoint _inside_ `viewDidLoad` and see if it is even being called. If not, that's the problem: the view is never being loaded.

Comment: Print EVERYTHING. Put a print in `viewDidLoad` and print out its view and all the subviews to see if anything is even being added to the view in the first place. If that doesn't work, keep adding prints everywhere. It's helped me solve some tough bugs.

Comment: Check in `.xib` or in `.storyboard` that view is connected to files owner and view have a proper class name

Comment: Ok Thank you I will try all of these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your Views in storyboard are connected to proper controller classes and you have set an entry point view in your storyboard. I saw several people unfortunately deleting entry point from storyboard. (small right indicating arrow in storyboard)